# Finding two different sub strings and printing everything between them in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, substring, character-arrays

```
String theString="gtcaatgccaataaagt";
char[] charArray = theString.toCharArray();
int len=theString.length();
boolean start = false,end1 = false;
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(charArray[i]=='a' && charArray[i+1]=='t' && charArray[i+2]=='g'){
        start=true;
    }
    if(charArray[i]=='t' && charArray[i+1]=='a' && charArray[i+2]=='a'){
        end1=true;
    }
}
while(start==true && end1==true){
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        System.out.println(charArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I want to print the characters between "atg" and "taa" from the string "theString"...
But with above code I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Don't know how to deal with it...And I think the mistake is in the first for loop..... but i don't know how to read "atg" first and then read "taa"

Comment: use `indexOf` and `subString()` methods

Comment: @SumedhJunghare Instead of commenting on your own question, please update your question and delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcdefghijk";
    int i1 = s.indexOf("cd")+2; // add index + length of substring (i.e, 2)
    int i2 = s.indexOf("ij");
    System.out.println(s.substring(i1,i2));

}

O/P :
efgh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are checking your index against the size of the String

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
```

but are accessing the String two characters after

```
if(charArray[i]=='a' && charArray[i+1]=='t' && charArray[i+2]=='g'){
```

Change your loop to

```
for(int i=0;i<len-2;i++){
```

Alternatively use the `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` methods in the String API.